# Can I wire ceiling fan light so that it is controlled by both a wall switch and pull chain

Tags: wiring

I would like a wall switch and the pull chain on my ceiling fan's light to work like my hall lights that are controlled by 3 way switches at the top and bottom of a stairway.  Is it possible to simulate this 3 way switch setup with travelers between the switches using a wall switch and a ceiling fan light pull chain?

Comment: Unlikely. Never heard of a 3-way switch as a pull chain, and you'd need new wiring in the walls.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, and I answered it based on that. Is it that you really *want* to use the pull chain? Or is that you want to be able to control the light from the switch (when entering/exiting the room) and *from someplace on the other side of the room* - i.e., for convenience someplace quite a distance from the door/switch, but not "must be via pull chain because I love pull chains"?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I don't have to have a pull chain.  Just looking for the convenience of control from a location where the pull chain currently exists or nearby  (over my bed, so I can turn out light when done reading or watching TV and not have to get out of bed). But, also want light control when I enter/exit the room.

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR No

The problem is that to do this you would need to modify the wiring of the fan/light itself. That would at a minimum invalidate the warranty. But it gets worse than that. The existing wires from the ceiling likely connect to the top of the fan/light. You would need to:

- Find an appropriately sized pull chain switch that can fit in place of the existing switch. The new switch would need to be a "3 way" design.
- Run new wires/cable from the wall switch to the top of the fan/light including travelers.
- Route wires connected to the travelers down to the new switch.
- Connect the original two pull chain switch wires (hot and switched hot) together in a safe way inside the fan/light.

It is just not practical.

This is actually one of the few *good* reasons I can see for a fan/light remote control. You can move the remote around, including, for example, keeping it next to a bed or sofa so that you can easily turn the light on/off without going to the other side of the room.

A practical solution I can think of is:

- Replace the wall switch with a smart switch, such as the Lutron Caseta, that has wireless remotes available.
- Instead of installing a Pico remote (using the Lutron Caseta example) in the wall (making it like a traditional 3-way switch in function, though not in wiring), use it as a handheld remote.

This will give you the "remote" advantage of a typical fan/light remote control while still retaining proper wall switch functionality which is normally lost when using a fan/light remote (how many houses have a piece of tape over the light switch because turning it off would disable the remote...)

Comment: Did a fast search before for 3 way pull switches.  I do think their 3 ways and my 3 ways are two different things.

Comment: SPDT is what you'd want, all the SPDT pull chain versions I found were SPDT **with an off position as well,** which would not work - and most were only rated 3-6A.